# How use native code in desktop flutter app?

Tags: flutter, desktop

I wanted to ask you about the desktop part of the technology.
If the documentation is about how ordinary developers can inject native code into a desktop application (WPF, Mac, Linux) like buinding or as a custom plugin or something similar
Best regards, Vadim

Comment: First check the docs on plugin development
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin
https://flutter.dev/desktop#plugin-support
reading the code for the path_provider or url_launcher desktop plugins can be a good start

Answer (score 2):

You have all the same options for platform code on desktop that you do on mobile:

- Adding it directly to the native runner app that's created by `flutter create`
- [Writing a plugin](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin)
- [FFI](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop)